# Add new in-app purcchase item after app available in apple store in itunesconnect

Tags: objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am uploading to app to apple store, But I want to add new items later , can I add new in-app purchases from itunes account when app will approved and ready for sale, I have set everything IAP from server and in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just have to ensure that your live app knows how to handle these purchases, i.e. if you add a new IAP to unlock a feature, your app needs to know about it before submitting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. As long as you have code to retrieve list of available IAP and show them in your app - you're fine.

One correction. The very **first IAP** that you create for your app you must submit along with the binary. After that when navigating to iTunes Connect you should see In-App Purchases tab in your application page:

[image]

Comment: Mean Can I add in-app purchases or Product ID in itunes when app is on apple store. without need to submit new version of app.

Comment: Please guide me how to add from itunes, because it not give any option to add in-app purchase to existing app.